# How to stop multiple thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Now i am going with the thread process,i have one thread and i'll run the thread for several time by increasing the count.
If i stop the thread by using thread instincts will it stop all the processing thread.

Here what i had tried:

```
      if (null != image && server.threadCount <=10) {
            startThread = new Thread(mThread);
            startThread.start();

        }
        else
        {
            server.threadCount--;
        }
    }


    public static class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            server.threadCount++;
        /*    if (server.threadCount <=10) {
        Log.v("count",String.valueOf(server.threadCount));
                server.threadCount++;
            } */
        }
    }
}
```

If i use  **startThread.interrupt();** will it stop hole thread or current.

I need to stop particular thread and also if need stop the whole thread.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context into what you're trying to achieve? Did you try using something like an Executor? Do you need to run the same thread 10 times? Sequentially? In parallel?

Comment: @kleinsenberg yes i need to run my thread sequentially after my goes across 10 i'll decrease one count and next image will add in list.i am getting the image in onpreviewframe

Comment: if use startThread.interrupt() will it stop the whole thread from 1 to 10 or particular current thread.

Comment: why don't you use threadpool

Comment: @L.Meng threadpool till now i didn't used it,ok let me check it out and know for  you.

Comment: i didn't get any proper tutorial can u plz guide me

Answer (score 2):

This would be an alternate solution that i provide here. First of all i must warn that using a count for threads is error prone and dangerous. As you may miss decrement or incrementing the variable due to some concurrency issue. I will provide here a solution for your above problem and also an alternate solution for your problem.

**SOLUTION FOR YOUR QUESTION :**

1. First thing is, in the above example you have reference to only one thread when you call startThread.interrupt(), as a result it will help you stop only one thread which you have referenced at that time.
2. Second i suggest you add the reference to a List, specially a concurrent collection or Synchronized collection. You can iterate your thread references from this list and call interrupt() when you wanted to flag interruption.

Ex :

```
List<Thread> threadList = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Thread>());
    ......
    startThread = new Thread(mThread);
         startThread.start();
    threadList.add(startThread);
    ......
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    synchronized(threadList) {
   Iterator<String> iterator = threadList.iterator(); 
   while (iterator.hasNext())
      Thread startThread = iterator.next();
    startThread.interrupt();
   }}
```

3. Stop the thread according to the Interrupted flag.

**ALTERNATE AND PREFERRED SOLUTION :**

1. Create a Threadpool with the number of threads you wanted to use. You can call shutdown() or shutdownNow()method to achieve the above.This call interrupts the threads which is processing the tasks.
   Ex:

   ```
   ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   executor.execute(YourRunnableHere); /*If you have 10 you can use a
                                  for loop to execute your runnables. */

   .......
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   executor.shutdownNow();
   }
   ```
2. In the above example you create a threadpool.

   - A threadpool is a pool of threads. The submitted or executed tasks on the executors are processed by the threads from the threadpool. Above you create a threadpool of 10 threads. Where 10 tasks can be executed in parallel by the executor.
   - The Executors are used to manage the execution of tasks. They are also used to interrupt the thread.
     This is a short intro for the above example.

You can learn more about the Executors and Threadpool online or reading a book "Java Concurrency in Practice" , for android "Efficient Android Threading". I hope it helped. thank you.

**SHORT TUTORIAL ON EXECUTOR :**

You can use the below link to learn about Executors or other concurrency utilities quickly. This gives you some knowledge one Concurrency Utilities. Note: Check the side Navigation Bar for other utilities.

[Short Tutorial on Executors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: Can you please guide me by any sample for this   List<String> threadList = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>()); because i am new to this i didn't get any proper link lot of waste of time on this please help me.

Comment: @Manoj Here is the link to a short tutorial on acquiring an Synchronized Collection. [Link Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-synchronize-a-list-or-other-collection-in-java.html) . I should advice that while using this list you need to use the Iterator inside the synchronized block. Also not all methods inside the Synchronized collection are actually synchronized. If you find an exception i suggest you to use some methods inside a synchronized block as the Iterator.

Comment: @Manoj The link here is an article which i took from internet. You can check it if you don't understand why i told you that some methods in synchronized collections are not actually synchronized. [Article Link Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15BZS3sdb6IILOHv3vzaTCsVr2rDE8hUXe7-bFezvSsI/edit?usp=sharing)  . i hope this helped.